# Separating numeric values from charaters from R studio, tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, type-conversion

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID <- c(1:10)
Response <- c("AUDIO", 6, 7, "Yes", 100, "AUDIO", 100, "NO", 9, 100)

tibble <- data.frame(ID, Response)
```

I want to filter out the character answers such as "AUDIO" and "Yes" to just leave the numerical values but are unsure how to get R to recognise the separate types. This is what I've tried so far.

```
new_tib <- tibble %>%
  mutate(Response = as.numeric(Response)) %>% 
  mutate(n = is.numeric(Response)) %>% 
  filter(n == TRUE) %>% 
  select(-n)
```

`as.numeric()` seems to coerce the character elements into their numeric levels, rather than convert them to `NA`. Is there any way to get as.numeric to coerce the characters to `NA` or a better way of separating these two types?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `subset(tibble, grepl('\\d', Response))`

Comment: You probably want `as.numeric(as.character(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Base R solution:

df_only_numeric_responses <- df[grepl('\\d+', df$Response),]


# Tidyverse solution: 

require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(grepl('\\d+', Response))

# Data: 

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1:10),
                 Response = c("AUDIO", 6, 7, "Yes", 100, "AUDIO", 100, "NO", 9, 100),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```